# No symbol found in windbg

Tags: windows-7, kernel, driver, windbg

I am trying to debug kernel in remote debugging using vmware and windbg.I have connected to target machine .My driver name is comint32.I have started the service of my driver in target machine .I want to view the dbgprint of my driver.Whenever I try to use break point I got an error "couldn't resolve error at 'comint32!DriverEntry'".This is the current status windbg output:

```
kd> x*!
start    end        module name
80bd1000 80bd9000   kdcom      (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\kdcom.pdb\F48BD9BC030C43D89689518F892586901\kdcom.pdb
82812000 82849000   hal        (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\halmacpi.pdb\AE605D6C59454802AE1D485E0B089A571\halmacpi.pdb
82849000 82c5b000   nt         (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\ntkrpamp.pdb\684DA42A30CC450F81C535B4D18944B12\ntkrpamp.pdb
82e09000 82e8e000   mcupdate_GenuineIntel   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.pdb\26689A9400E04CF6AD63DC2E608DAA9C1\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.pdb
82e8e000 82e9f000   PSHED      (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\pshed.pdb\5ACEAFD8AD3A46FEAD083AFDF675DA391\pshed.pdb
82e9f000 82ea7000   BOOTVID    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\bootvid.pdb\10C3ABD4165D4ED3A9493BB094B44AEA1\bootvid.pdb
82ea7000 82ee9000   CLFS       (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\clfs.pdb\04F22EAC7BD04A1BA81A6FB5D319649F1\clfs.pdb
82ee9000 82f94000   CI         (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\ci.pdb\3358E6E48A5245F6AB97EA05356E020F1\ci.pdb
82f94000 82fdf000   volmgrx    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\volmgrx.pdb\433F00DD3CC34DE8BC3F9E4BDDACA5EE1\volmgrx.pdb
82fdf000 82fed000   PCIIDEX    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\pciidex.pdb\8B7BC6201128486CB5B03916EBD5FF8E1\pciidex.pdb
83800000 83807000   intelide   (no symbols)           
8380a000 8387cd00   dsfksvcs   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\dsfksvcs.pdb\EE67C173CB4C4B31BA3806038D42B3C01\dsfksvcs.pdb
8387d000 838b8500   DSFOleaut32   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\DSFOleaut32.pdb\F02C6A23966243E1B10F05EB634A88331\DSFOleaut32.pdb
838b9000 8392a000   Wdf01000   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\Wdf01000.pdb\A9E46808F4F748178D3071AA9EE76FB71\Wdf01000.pdb
8392a000 83938000   WDFLDR     (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\wdfldr.pdb\95D9DB57778548E6B6774520468479891\wdfldr.pdb
83938000 83980000   ACPI       (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\acpi.pdb\E7300A0CC3524834A4E1E55773C1901E1\acpi.pdb
83980000 83989000   WMILIB     (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\wmilib.pdb\F52B38A4800849D48BFFD48715A446A51\wmilib.pdb
83989000 83991000   msisadrv   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\msisadrv.pdb\5D6926DA4AD1474BAE8CBDA5909F68201\msisadrv.pdb
83991000 839bb000   pci        (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\pci.pdb\2E2A912260694615A7E97AFBA3FA934E1\pci.pdb
839bb000 839c6000   vdrvroot   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\vdrvroot.pdb\3C9D6939EF564015B8D0728611C88C221\vdrvroot.pdb
839c6000 839d7000   partmgr    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\partmgr.pdb\7CA861FF7879483ABA38CE28186F293E2\partmgr.pdb
839d7000 839df000   compbatt   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\compbatt.pdb\EE14F03B54BF49B4B62A0EF912A59C8F1\compbatt.pdb
839df000 839ea000   BATTC      (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\battc.pdb\53C47BEA2F08470BB58DFD1566285EC71\battc.pdb
839ea000 839fa000   volmgr     (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\volmgr.pdb\4AF04B598C494297B1C69F95823AA9F81\volmgr.pdb
83a24000 83a3a000   mountmgr   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\mountmgr.pdb\356DDF9839E040638E034EEA956C28F81\mountmgr.pdb
83a3a000 83a43000   atapi      (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\atapi.pdb\EF544461A5D5482980C2CA01640A6D621\atapi.pdb
83a43000 83a66000   ataport    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\ataport.pdb\C9AF9FE9166548FD86EFAC017F6023011\ataport.pdb
83a66000 83a7e000   lsi_sas    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\lsi_sas.pdb\FCC2DAF36299423A9765B62D750A97461\lsi_sas.pdb
83a7e000 83ac6000   storport   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\storport.pdb\E19FF676062D46A69EB1BB6A916896172\storport.pdb
83ac6000 83acf000   amdxata    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\amdxata.pdb\5E66F230920844408A1EE389D50B6B4A1\amdxata.pdb
83acf000 83b03000   fltmgr     (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\fltMgr.pdb\E6CA9E082E70438988788CB58DB340B01\fltMgr.pdb
83b03000 83b14000   fileinfo   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\fileinfo.pdb\EBD1E885413A4242AA515F1B06BB564F1\fileinfo.pdb
83b14000 83bcb000   ndis       (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\ndis.pdb\4DAAA54E2C26455DB2471D696BC8E6A62\ndis.pdb
83bcb000 83bfc000   fwpkclnt   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\fwpkclnt.pdb\FDE8223F22C54AEA8061EE56EA16A0251\fwpkclnt.pdb
88c00000 88c0e000   pcw        (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\pcw.pdb\D368300F340A423EBBA32FBDDDEC24B91\pcw.pdb
88c0e000 88c17000   Fs_Rec     (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\fs_rec.pdb\3465ED05A901452FAD07E77351F094591\fs_rec.pdb
88c2b000 88d5a000   Ntfs       (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\ntfs.pdb\04B176C327B240F7A576F3417A7B95032\ntfs.pdb
88d5a000 88d85000   msrpc      (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\msrpc.pdb\B4C428CFD1024C43BD3E2B10D1A8F0711\msrpc.pdb
88d85000 88d98000   ksecdd     (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\ksecdd.pdb\E84CBB7448354030A32188581CC8B37A1\ksecdd.pdb
88d98000 88df5000   cng        (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\cng.pdb\3F94705B83A0481DA755FA6A70729BDE1\cng.pdb
88df5000 88dfb000   comint32   (no symbols)           
88e25000 88e63000   NETIO      (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\netio.pdb\7A33726ABE884384BFDFB951F05D13AC2\netio.pdb
88e63000 88e88000   ksecpkg    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\ksecpkg.pdb\3D42090DFF4E4D55985F577277A3B1E91\ksecpkg.pdb
88e88000 88fd2000   tcpip      (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\tcpip.pdb\0FD6F17209C1481C9008CCDB468746392\tcpip.pdb
88fd2000 88fd7580   dsfroot    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\dsfroot.pdb\95EE5096213948909946E4333289A97F1\dsfroot.pdb
88fd8000 88fe0380   vmstorfl   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\vmstorfl.pdb\D7FD176CC0134139B2EE4BEAF352AEE41\vmstorfl.pdb
89032000 89071000   volsnap    (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\volsnap.pdb\1F66E7165E8F4BD982A34A9DFA1BBFD31\volsnap.pdb
89071000 89079000   spldr      (no symbols)           
89079000 890a6000   rdyboost   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\rdyboost.pdb\53BB42ABE1404332962CA2AEA8301D331\rdyboost.pdb
890a6000 890b6000   mup        (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\mup.pdb\E96F69551E2447289250F71FB5AB6E0C2\mup.pdb
890b6000 890be000   hwpolicy   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\hwpolicy.pdb\0F041CEBADCA48F4BC65F68463272F1D1\hwpolicy.pdb
890be000 890f0000   fvevol     (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\fvevol.pdb\DC4549C710EE425F8956C7D82BFE83651\fvevol.pdb
890f0000 89101000   disk       (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\disk.pdb\D2AD04F7F4BF45C8A8F0E2BF689326F11\disk.pdb
89101000 89126000   CLASSPNP   (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\classpnp.pdb\64A86A6AD27D4730A78ECC25166E13562\classpnp.pdb
89126000 89136000   agp440     (pdb symbols)          C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\agp440.pdb\BDB51BE7BF024CCF893C1E44B0C266C71\agp440.pdb



kd> .reload /f comint32

"comint32" was not found in the image list.
Debugger will attempt to load "comint32" at given base 00000000.

Please provide the full image name, including the extension (i.e. kernel32.dll)
for more reliable results.Base address and size overrides can be given as
.reload <image.ext>=<base>,<size>.
DBGENG:  comint32 - Partial symbol image load missing image info
DBGHELP: No header for comint32.  Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: c:\chapter03ghost\src\objchk_win7_x86\i386\comint32.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: .\comint32.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: comint32 missing debug info.  Searching for pdb anyway
DBGHELP: Can't use symbol server for comint32.pdb - no header information available
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\comint32.pdb\5E9D372C84174583B2DD476990BF10BA1\comint32.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: comint32_0 - private symbols & lines 
         C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\sym\comint32.pdb\5E9D372C84174583B2DD476990BF10BA1\comint32.pdb - unmatched
Unable to add module at 00000000

the symbol path of windbg:
kd> .sympath
Symbol search path is: srv*;C:\Chapter03Ghost\bin
Expanded Symbol search path is: cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\chapter03ghost\bin
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your `Whenever I try to use break point I got an error "couldn't resolve error at 'comint32!DriverEntry'"`? What do you do exactly? Where do you see this error?

Comment: when i try this   kd> bu comint32!DriverEntry
Couldn't resolve error at 'comint32!DriverEntry'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that the driver is loaded. You can do this using `lm` or `lmvm comint32` the first command will list all modules, the second one will give you detailed information on the comint32. If it isn't listed in the loaded modules, then most likely the driver hasn't been loaded yet. If it is loaded then that's a little odd for it to give this error, but I'm guessing it's not loaded.

Comment: I have solve this error.i have copied the mismatched pdb in corresponding directory